# Is there any programmatic workaround to perform chain of actions on selectors in playwright?

Tags: javascript, typescript, selector, playwright, chaining

According to the official documentation, the playwright doesn't support chaining the actions you perform on a single selector like, alternatively, Cypress allows for.
As a result, your code file grows with repetitive expressions:

```
await page.getByRole('textbox').click();
await page.getByRole('textbox').fill('test value in the text box');
await page.getByRole('textbox').press('Enter');
```

What I'm trying to achieve: is that after you perform a click, you can perform a fill and maybe a press, if it's programmatically possible, in a single expression. Without repeating
`await page.getByRole('textbox')`

I'm relatively new to javascript and typescript. I'm reading the documentation but feeling overwhelmed. I would be grateful for any guidance concerning if, e.g., promises would solve this issue, with an example on the above code provided.

Using "@playwright/test": "^1.28.0"

Comment: How about saving the element in a variable first? `const el = page.getByRole('textbox'); await el.click(); await el.fill(...); await el.press(...)` (but the await is still in need of repeating because each individual operation here is asynchronous)

Comment: Another option would be to create a wrapper object that implements the chaining.

Comment: @CherryDT Tried this out, test passed. That's a one way indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your code by moving the Locator to a variable and reuse that.
So something like this:

```
const myTextbox = page.getByRole('textbox');
await myTextbox.click();
await myTextbox.fill('some text');
await myTextbox.press('Enter');
```

Not sure what your Use Case is but by using [fill](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-fill) you can usually already skip the click beforehand. Not even sure if you need the enter there for it to work.

I do not think it is possible to chain all those actions without making it overly complicated or hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for this proposition. That's a halfway to what I tried to achieve. You were right about the .click(), but press ('Enter') must remain in place. 

For the context, my use case is to write automated tests for https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dynamic_controls, "Enable/disable" part.

Answer (score 0):

This might work (using [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)). I didn't try, I don't use this library and I probably made too simplistic assumptions about the types but it should be a good start.

```js
type ChainLocator = {
    [K in keyof Locator]: Locator[K] extends ((...args: any[]) => Promise<void>)
        ? (...args: Parameters<Locator[K]>) => ChainLocator : Locator[K]
} & { run: () => Promise<void> }


const chain = (selector: Locator): ChainLocator => {
    const queue: ((...args: any[]) => Promise<void>)[] = [];
    const proxy = new Proxy(selector, {
        get: (target, key: keyof ChainLocator) => 
            key === 'run' ? async () => {
                for (const f of queue) await f(selector)
            }
            
            : (typeof target[key] === 'function') ? (...args: any[]) => {
                queue.push(target[key].bind(target, args));
                return proxy;
            }

            : target[key]
        
    });
    return proxy;
}


chain(page.getByRole('textbox'))
    .click().fill('test value in the text box').press('Enter').run();
```

Now yet another way to do it is to chain function calls

```js
const chain = (selector: Locator) =>
    async (...fs: ((a: Locator) => Promise<void>)[]) => {
        for (const f of fs) await f(selector);
    }

chain(page.getByRole('textbox'))(
    s => s.click(),
    s => s.fill('test value in the text box'),
    s => s.press('Enter')
)
```

It's a little verbose because the API is not functional. Ideally we would like something like this

```js
const { click, fill, press } = curryMethods(theLocatorClass);
 
chain(page.getByRole('textbox'))(
    click(),
    fill('test value in the text box'),
    press('Enter')
)
```

That's possible. Hard or even impossible to type for the general case, but if we make the same assumptions as for the Proxy version (no need for generics, no need to care about the return type), it's approachable.

Comment: While technically possible, this seems like pretty clear proof that it's better to write normal, boring Playwright code that everyone understands.

Comment: There is nothing fancy or unnatural about the first approach. The API seems to be 100% effectful, so there is no ambiguity. If I used this lib I would monkey patch it without a second thought, and maintainers would just assume it's part of the native API, or I would wrap the lib in a fully functional API. No shame in having a mirror of an existing lib with a different API. You just have to document it, and the documentation is as simple as replacing methods with functions.

Comment: I strongly disagree. All of that is a good deal of extra friction for anyone that uses Playwright. It's a totally custom wrapper that needs to be documented and learned. Examples need to be adapted to it continually. Code is unreadable for new developers until they learn the chained style. All just to avoid a few `await page.` calls. It's essentially a new custom library dependency that needs to be maintained. I'm fine with this as a proof of concept, but not something that should actually be done except maybe in personal projects, for fun.

Comment: I agree that if this was to be turned into something real, more care should be put into checking that there is a 1:1 mapping between the APIs. There should be nothing to learn. You don't need to document the whole API just to tell users that methods return the instance or that methods are turned into functions. It is exactly the same API (IF every method is a command and not a query) with a different syntax.

Comment: Just to be clear: my preferred course of action if I cared, which I don't, would be to present the use case to playwright maintainers with an issue and a pull request. I don't understand why it is not part of the API.

Comment: The reason is because it's not an FP-style library like Cypress. Most modern async JS libraries use this imperative style, so it's a conscious choice, not an oversight. Feel free to present it, and if it's accepted and adopted by the community, that's fine, and different than what you proposed above with creating a mirror.

Comment: I don't think making and API chainable makes it less imperative, but now that I think about it a little more I can see that you do need to be sure you don't run into a command/query confusion when you change the return value of methods globally. If your solution is either a hack or a wrapper/mirror, It is going to be fragile if the lib changes and breaks your assumptions about this. And it does limit its use to personal projects

Answer (score 0):

If your application doesn't explicitly need the `click`, you can get away without it in Playwright, and just `fill()` immediately:

```
await page.getByRole('textbox').fill('test value in the text box');
await page.getByRole('textbox').press('Enter');
```

Comment: This is a good point, but I'd still consider [storing the locator in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74640181/6243352).